# Should MTSUser,administrator be LDAP or Windows?

Tags: 2013, ldap

I install Tridion 2013 SP1, and it will use LDAP as authentication.

When installing Tridion, following users are required.

- MTSUser
- Administrator user(TCME administrator account)

When using LDAP, should those accounts be LDAP directory service user,
or Windows user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MTSUser must be a windows account, as this account will interact with the OS quite often. During installation, the Administrator account must be a Windows account too, as you will not be able to login to Tridion with an LDAP user immediately after installing the server (there's some additional configuration steps to follow).

So, in short - both should be Windows accounts.